# Trouble with creating table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have got the current code https://jsfiddle.net/rjw3f7yu/5/ that can plot table in HTML using Javascript code. However, there is this line that pops up stating "undefined" between row 1 and 2. Anyone knows what could be the problem here?

I am using bootstrap v3 just for extra info. Thanks!

HTML code:

```
<table class="table" id="wconclusiontable">
                      </table>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var counttopercentagec1event = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var counttopercentagec2event = [2, 33, 22, 32, 43, 52];
var counttopercentagec3event = [7, 17, 72, 37, 47, 51];


function wconclusiontable() {
  var wtable = document.getElementById("wconclusiontable");
  var row;


  row += "<thead><tr><th>" + "Event #" + "</th>";                                   
  row += "<th>" + "Low" + "</th>";
  row += "<th>" + "Medium" + "</th>";
  row += "<th>" + "High" + "</th>";
  row += "</tr></thead>";


  for (var i = 2; i <  5; i++) {
    row += "<tbody><tr><td>" + (i-1) + "</td>";                                 
    row += "<td>" + counttopercentagec1event[i-1] + "%" + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + counttopercentagec2event[i-1] + "%" + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + counttopercentagec3event[i-1] + "%" + "</td>";                  
    row += "</tr></tbody>";
  }


  wtable.innerHTML = row;
}
 wconclusiontable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you never initialize your variable, "row". Initially, row is therefore undefined.

When you add to it the first time, you'll basically concatenate the strings "undefined" with "Event #".

Try defining row as:

```
var row = "";
```

Your updated code:

```
function wconclusiontable() {
  var wtable = document.getElementById("wconclusiontable");
  var row = "";


  row += "<thead><tr><th>" + "Event #" + "</th>";                                   
  row += "<th>" + "Low" + "</th>";
  row += "<th>" + "Medium" + "</th>";
  row += "<th>" + "High" + "</th>";
  row += "</tr></thead>";


  for (var i = 2; i <  5; i++) {
    row += "<tbody><tr><td>" + (i-1) + "</td>";                                 
    row += "<td>" + counttopercentagec1event[i-1] + "%" + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + counttopercentagec2event[i-1] + "%" + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + counttopercentagec3event[i-1] + "%" + "</td>";                  
    row += "</tr></tbody>";
  }


  wtable.innerHTML = row;
}
```

Declaring a variable in a function in JavaScript generally serves one purpose - to set the scope of that variable, and avoid collision with a global variable. Since JavaScript is dynamically typed, JavaScript has no clue what it should be initializing your variable to at first. So, it chooses to define it as an "undefined" object.

During string concatenation, JavaScript will type coerce all objects involved in the operation to a string. This includes "undefined".

Why, then, does undefined appear after the header of the table? This happens because HTML renders the thead of the table before anything else. The best way to figure out what the potential issue is when dealing with a JavaScript issue like this is to open the inspector by right clicking the problematic element on the page and choosing "Inspect Element".

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborations!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialise var row with empty string. Since row is undefined initially and you're adding directly with string, the initial row variable's value undefined is getting added. Hope that helps

Update fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rjw3f7yu/6/

```
var row = '';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

`var row;`

Replace above line by this

`var row = new String("");`

https://jsfiddle.net/wxaty4xs/